# replacing nested for loop with sapply in R

Tags: r, sapply, seq

So I have 10 parameters, with 7 fixed and 3 varying using `seq`. Each varying parameter has 10 possibilities. Right now I create an empty data frame and fill it after going through a bunch of functions and generating an output for each combination of parameters. So there is 1000 (10*10*10) possibilities. Right now I use nested for loops. Lets say m,g, and x are my varying parameters. Here is an example.

```
m.c <- seq(1,10, by=1)  
m.i <- seq(1,10, by=1) * 0.5
a <-  .5 
b <-  1
c <-  .5
gg <-  seq(.02,.2, by=.02)
n <-  7
r <-  .25
alpha <-  2
dt <-  1
X <-  seq(.01,.1, by=.01)
intervention.data <-  data.frame(intervention = numeric())
parameter.data <-  data.frame(m=numeric(), g=numeric(), X=numeric())

A.c = function(m = m.c,a,b,c,g,n,r,alpha,dt,X) { 
    1 - exp(-dt*(1/(alpha*dt)*log(1+(alpha*b*dt*m*a^2*c*X*exp(-g*n))/(a*c*X+g))))
}

A.i = function(m = m.i,a,b,c,g,n,r,alpha,dt,X) { 
    1 - exp(-dt*(1/(alpha*dt)*log(1+(alpha*b*dt*m*a^2*c*X*exp(-g*n))/(a*c*X+g))))
}

for (i in 1:length(mm)) {
  m = mm[i]

  for (ii in 1:length(gg)) {
    g = gg[ii]

    for (iii in 1:length(XX)) { 
      X = XX[iii]

      parameter.data = rbind(parameter.data, data.frame(m=m, g=g, X=X))

      a.c = A.c(m = m.c,a,b,c,g,n,r,alpha,dt,X)
      a.i = A.i(m = m.i,a,b,c,g,n,r,alpha,dt,X)

      intervention.effect= a.i/a.c

      intervention.data = rbind(intervention.data, data.frame( intervention = intervention.effect))
    }
  }
}

all.intervention.data = cbind(parameter.data, intervention.data)
```

What I have works but seems pretty inefficient so I have been trying to find how to use sapply or lapply but have not been successful in understanding to use them so all the combos. are made. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please provide a *working* example. sounds like you just need `expand.grid(mm, gg, xx)` anyway

Comment: The edit should provide the extra detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have lost `mm` in your data, so I can not follow perfectly, but a better way to do this would be to vectorize:

```
all.data <- expand.grid(m.c = m.c,gg = gg,X = X)
all.data$m.i <- all.data$m.c * 0.5

all.data$a.c <- A.c(m = all.data$m.c,a,b,c,all.data$gg,n,r,alpha,dt,all.data$X)
all.data$a.i <- A.i(m = all.data$m.i,a,b,c,all.data$gg,n,r,alpha,dt,all.data$X)
```

Comment: That does seem to work. Also i meant to change the mm. It is m.c and m.i that I wanted so that works great. Thanks!